# Replace lines with specific string and save with the same name

Tags: powershell, logging

I'm working with an application that creates a log file. Due to an error in the software itself, it keeps producing three errors I'm not interested in. Each line has a unique identifier so I can't just replace the line since each one is different.

I have two main issues with this: I need to save it with the same name, and while it works the file should be available (in case the logger needs to write something).

I can't hard-code the original app to prevent it from writing that part of the log.

I have tried so far:

```
Get-Content log.log | Where-Object {$_-notmatch 'ERROR1' -And $_-notmatch 'ERROR2' -And $_-notmatch 'ERROR3' } `|Set-Content log_stripped.log
```

^ It only works if the output file has a different name.

```
Get-Content error.log | foreach-object { Where-Object {$_-notmatch 'ERROR1' -And $_-notmatch 'ERROR2' -And $_-notmatch 'ERROR3' } } | Set-Content error.log
```

^ This one froze my PS session.

I also tried reading the file to a variable:

```
$logcontent = ${h:error.log}
```

but I got System.OutOfMemoryException.

Ideally, what I need is something that reads the log file, takes away all the lines I don't want, and then save it with its original name.

Ideas? (Keep in mind that the log file is +/- 900 MB with the unnecesary data and 45mb once I strip the data with the first method - but I need it to save the file with its original name)

Comment: Why do you need to save it with the same name? I don't think that's a good idea. If the file is locked while it is being written, the logging system may fail to log entries (depending on how sophisticated it is).

Answer (score 1):

You can't save the file back to the same name while you're still reading from it, which means you'd have to read the whole 900MB into memory before you start writing.  Not a good idea.

Try this:

```
Remove-Item log_stripped.log

Get-Content log.log -ReadCount 1000 | 
foreach {$_ -notmatch 'ERROR1|ERROR2|ERROR3' | Add-Content log_stripped.log }

Remove-item log.log
Rename-Item log_stripped.log log.log
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you want to save to the same filename, but if the reason you want that is that you want the log to be continuously updated, then you could do the following:

```
Get-Content -Wait log.log | 
    ? {$_ -notmatch 'ERROR1|ERROR2|ERROR3' } |
    Out-File log_stripped.log
```

Note the -Wait on the Get-Content.

`log_stripped.log` will be continuously updated as `log.log` is updated.